# How to add GET-paramter causing Varnish serving uncached page

Tags: varnish

I want to add a paramter to some URL that allows me to server a page uncache. So something like https://example.org/foo/baa?uncached should be server by the application servers where as https://example.org/foo/baa might be servered by directly from varnish's cache.

To do so I tried to add

```
if (req.url ~ "^/\?uncached") {
    set req.http.X-VC-Cacheable = "NO:On user request";
    return(pass);
}
```

to my vcl_recv. But somehow this did not work (caching behavior is not toggled). Is this the right approach? What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```cpp
if (req.url ~ "\?uncached") {
    set req.http.X-VC-Cacheable = "NO:On user request";
    return(pass);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was faulty RegEx:

```
if (req.url ~ "^/\?uncached") {
```

Is only working for URL without any local part. Whereas:

```
if (req.url ~ "\?uncached") {
    set req.http.X-VC-Cacheable = "NO:On user request";
    return(pass);
}
```

workds for every URL where uncached is the first parameter.